# need help to split array into menu in javascript before my head explodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, split, substr

using javascript I have an array which is

```
[{"id":171,
"children":
    [{"id":172},
    {"id":170},
    {"id":173}]},
{"id":174},
{"id":175}]
```

this is made from a nestable jQuery list

I now need to push that into another array which has a structure of id, top_menu, submenu

I am trying to run a for loop looking for ',' and then what come before the comma dictates whether its a top_menu item of a sub_menu item and if its a sub_menu item, what is its parent menu

I have tried approxamatley 15 different loops, but all are failing on one level or another.

Am I missing a function that can easily do this?

I have bee using str.split(','); to find the comma and then using search and substr to try and determine the level of the menu.

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: What's exactly the desired result ?

Comment: desired result would be

array[0]="1","0","170"
array[1]="1","0","171"
array[2]="0","1","172"
array[3]="0","1","173"
array[4]="1","0","174"
array[5]="1","0","175"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort this out but rebuilding the string into a format that I could easily push into the array

heres the code

```
var str='[{"id":170},{"id":171,"children":[{"id":172},{"id":173}]},{"id":174,"children":[{"id":176},{"id":177}]},{"id":175}]';

for(var d=0; d<str.length;d++){
  if(newstr!=''){str=newstr;}           
    var childrenstart=str.indexOf("children");
    if(childrenstart!="-1"){
       var endstr=str.substr(childrenstart).indexOf("]");;
   var childrenstring=str.substr(childrenstart,endstr);
   var cleanchildrenstr=childrenstring.replace(/children":/gi,'');
   var newchildrenstrng=cleanchildrenstr.replace(/id/gi,'child');
   newstr=str.substr(0,childrenstart-1)+newchildrenstrng+str.substr(childrenstart+endstr);
   d=childrenstart+endstr;
 } else {
   d=str.length;
 }
}

 var finalstr=str.replace(/{/gi,'');        
 var finalstr=finalstr.replace(/}/gi,'');       
 var finalstr=finalstr.replace(/]/gi,'');       
 var finalstr=finalstr.replace(/\[/gi,'');      
 var finalstr=finalstr.replace(/\"/gi,'');
```

I know this can be written smarter and neater but its a first draft and works. this returns a string of

```
id:170,id:171,child:172,child:173,id:174,id:175
```

which can be chopped up and pushed into the array

Answer (score 0):

```
var menu =[{"id":171,
"children":
    [{"id":172},
    {"id":170},
    {"id":173}]},
{"id":174},
{"id":175}];

for( node in menu){
    console.log(node);
    if(menu[node].children){
        //submenu logic here
        console.log(menu[node].children);   
    }
}
```

I think my syntax can be cleaned a bit, but this will parse a nested array.

Comment: sorry but I dont know what to do with this. My js is noobie level. can you tell me what this does?

Comment: this will iterate through the menu array. If one of the menus has a submenu, the comment '//submenu' will get hit. Once you know it has submenus, you can iterate through the submenus, print them out etc.

Comment: I put your code into my code with an alert in each for loop and also one in the child if statment like this var menu =[{"id":171,
"children":
    [{"id":172},
    {"id":170},
    {"id":173}]},
{"id":174},
{"id":175}];

for( node in menu){
    console.log(node);
 alert("toplevel");
    if(menu[node].children){
        alert("sublevel");
        console.log(menu[node].children);   
    }
} all this gave me was one sublevel alert. I can get this just by searching 'children' in the string. the problem is that 'children' is not infront of each child, just the first one

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding the issue. I think you could have just done another foreach loop once you find a children node to iterate through the array since it looks to be a valid JSON object.